# Limit esp8266 AP broadcast range

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266

Turned esp8266 as an access point that will be connected by other mobile devices, want to connect only the mobile is very near(2-3 feet) to this access point, used the following code to limit the transmission power. But it is not working

```
    WiFi.softAP(ssid);
    WiFi.setOutputPower(-500);
```

Is there any other way for me to make it work?

Comment: According to the implementation at https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/src/ESP8266WiFiGeneric.cpp#L280 your code should be equivalent to `system_phy_set_max_tpw(0)`. (http://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/20b-esp8266_rtos_sdk_api_reference_v1.4.0_0.pdf). Could you try to define the function as `void system_phy_set_max_tpw(uint8_t maxPwr);` and call it directly? Also https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/1971 indicates that this could be a bug within the newer Espressif SDKs after 2.0.0.

Comment: Yes, I had tried it, not working

Comment: Then open an issue on that arduino-esp8266 github repository to get the maintainers attention to fix it. If it's a bug in the Espressif SDK, you can't do anything but use an older version with an older SDK.

Comment: from the source: `max: +20.5dBm min: 0dBm`, -500 won't work...  if you can afford it, try cutting the trace on the pcb antenna, whittling it down a bit at time. This will cause more power and time to be used, as the chip has to correct for a mal-tuned transceiver, but it will lower the range a lot. can try electrical tape and a foil wrapping as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can not use -ve values or not more than +20.5 (max: +20.5dBm min: 0.0dBm)
try this

WiFi.setOutputPower(0.0);